# findByExample in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

Is there a method in **Doctrine** like **Hibernate**'s `findByExample` method?

thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `findBy` method, which is inherited and is present in all repositories.

Example:

```
$criteria = array('name' => 'someValue', 'status' => 'enabled');
$result = $em->getRepository('SomeEntity')->findBy($criteria);
```

You can create `findByExample` method in one of your repositories using a definition like this:

```
class MyRepository extends Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository {
    public function findByExample(MyEntity $entity) {
        return $this->findBy($entity->toArray());
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, you will have to create your own base class for the entities, implementing the `toArray` method.

`MyEntity` can also be an interface, which your specific entities will have to implement the `toArray` method again.

To make this available in all your repositories, ensure that you are extending your base repository class - in this example, the `MyRepository` one.

*P.S I assume you are talking about **Doctrine 2.x***

Comment: Im not talking about Doctrine2 (i made question o late 2010), but for now, its solves the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

Let's say you have a model called Users.  You have the following two classes

```
abstract class Base_User extends Doctrine_Record 
{
   //define table, columns, etc
}

class User extends Base_User
{

}
```

in some other object you can do

```
$user = new User;

//This will return a Doctrine Collection of all users with first name = Travis
$user->getTable()->findByFirstName("Travis");

//The above code is actually an alias for this function call
$user->getTable()->findBy("first_name", "Travis");

//This will return a Doctrine Record for the user with id = 24
$user->getTable()->find(24);

//This will return a Doctrine Collection for all users with name=Raphael and 
//type = developer
$user->getTable()
     ->findByDql("User.name= ? AND User.type = ?", array("Raphael", "developer"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Travis, but it's not what im looking for. I wanna do something like this: 
$user = new User;
$user->name="rafael";
$user->category="developer";
$q = Doctrine::getTable('User')->findByExample($user);

and $q should return a collection of users with "rafael" as name and "developer" as category. Do you know how can do that?

Comment: Check the last piece of code that uses the findByDql method.  That should get you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
$users = $userTable->findByIsAdminAndIsModeratorOrIsSuperAdmin(true, true, true);
```

See http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en