# how to get associate entity object doctrine2

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, entity, associate

how to get associate entity object doctrine2. I have the value of **"userId"**, now i am trying to get the value of **"apartmentId"**. But it shows a error like ----
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT user_publishers(publisherId) VALUES (347) ':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (347)' at line 1

This is how i am trying to get the value of "apartmentId" ---

```
$selectData = "SELECT user_apartments(apartmentId) VALUES ($userId) ";

        $selectData = $em->getConnection()->prepare($selectData); 
        $selectData->execute();

        print_r($selectData);
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this problem. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. If you want to use a native sql query you should something along these lines:

**Example:**

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
// build rsm here

$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery('SELECT id, name, discr FROM users WHERE name = ?', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, 'romanb');

$users = $query->getResult();
```

***Source:*** http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

You would be better of however mapping your table as an entity in doctrine and use the repository's `findBy` method.

**Example:**

```
$em = new EntityManager();
$criteria = array('name' => 'someValue', 'status' => 'enabled');
$result = $em->getRepository('SomeEntity')->findBy($criteria);
```

***Source:*** https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432032/2853903

***Note:*** The snippets above are to give an indication and were not tested.